# Is stellarpool.net safe?

Tags: inflation

Is stellarpool.net safe enough so that the BLACKWALLET disaster will not happen to this inflation pool? As we know what happened before about people losing a lot of their coins during online transactions.

Answer (score 1):

The blackwallet hack happened due to a hacker changing the script in the site to automatically send their wallet all the lumens in the wallet entered, since one had to insert a private key to access their wallet.

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Stellar/comments/7q9g31/statement_blackwallet_hacks_update/)

**Stellarpool.net is an inflation pool. The worst that can happen when you put their address in as your inflation destination is not recieving payment.**

Don't put your private key ANYWHERE but stellar.org.